# Double digit 30 seconds countdown

Tags: javascript, html, double, countdown

I would like to have the countdown like

> :10, :09, :08

and so on. Please help a beginner.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timeleft = 30;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = ":" + timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        window.location.replace("next_slide.html");
        }
    },1000);

</script>
```

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`. I've removed your misleading Java question tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can proceed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timeleft = 30;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = ":" + ((timeleft >= 10) ? timeleft : ("0" + timeleft));
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        window.location.replace("next_slide.html");
        }
    },1000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were asking for:

```
    var timeleft = 30;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;

    if (timeleft < 10) {
        suffix = ':0';
    } else {
        suffix = ':'
    };
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = suffix + timeleft;

    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        window.location.replace("next_slide.html");
        }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve added a sample of a working timer and how I typically set it up.  I’m using jQuery but put how you would do the same line without it.

```
function startTimer() {
    $("#timeIndicator").text(TIMER_CONSTANT);
    //document.getElementById(“timeIndicator”).textContent = TIMER_CONSTANT;

    setInterval(function() {
        TIMER_CONSTANT --;
        if(TIMER_CONSTANT >=0) {
            $("#timeIndicator").text(TIMER_CONSTANT);
            //document.getElementById(“timeIndicator”).textContent = TIMER_CONSTANT;
        }
        if(TIMER_CONSTANT === 0) {
            clearInterval(TIMER_CONSTANT);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

What is your `countdownTimer` element? What is currently occurring in your code? What is the unexpected output of any?